# vba excel partial string search

Tags: string, excel, vba

```
  With Worksheets("Sheet2")
  NewRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


.Range("A" & NewRow) = ws.Range("A91")
.Range("B" & NewRow) = ws.Range("A92")


If ws.Range("A93") = "LN:" &  Then
    .Range("C" & NewRow) = ws.Range("A94")
Else
    .Range("C" & NewRow) = ws.Range("A93")
 End If


End With
```

How can I change that line:

```
  If ws.Range("A93") = "LN:" &   Then
```

Code should copy cell A94 if text in cell A93 starts with:  ***LN:***
regardless what characters are following LN:

Comment: You could use `Instr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the Like operator with a wildcard

```
If ws.Range("A93") Like "LN:*" &  Then
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the VBA `LEFT()` string function:

```
If Left(ws.range("A93").value, 3) = "LN:" Then
```

That will take the 3 leftmost characters of the range's value and compare it to the string "LN:"